# Splitting Excel Tabs to Separate Files

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm trying to write a C#.NET function to split Excel worksheets into separate files. I'm using Excel Interop but I can't seem to get it to work like I want.  The best I'm able to do is resave the file with a specific tab selected. The MSDN documentation seems very unclear on which functions to use. I read somewhere else that some of these functions aren't behaving as expected wither.

```
               private void SplitFile(string targetPath, string sourceFile)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlFile;
        //Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        string exportFormat = "";
        if (cboExcel.Checked == true) //set the output format
            exportFormat = "XLSX";
        else if (cboCsv.Checked == true)
            exportFormat = "CSV";
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Error detecting output format");

        xlApp = new Excel.Application(); //object for controlling Excel
        xlFile = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(txtFilePath.Text, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0); //open the source file
        //xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlFile.Worksheets.get_Item(1); //Select the first tab in the file. Note: Index does NOT start are zero.


        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false; //override Excel save dialog message
        int TabCount = xlFile.Worksheets.Count; //total count of the tabs in the file

        int sheetCount = 0; //this will be used to output the number of exported sheets
        for (int i = 1; i <= TabCount; i++) //for each sheet in the workbook...
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + ": " + xlFile.Worksheets.Item[i].Name);
            xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[i].Select();
            string sheetName = xlFile.Sheets[i].Name; //..get the name of the sheet. It will be used for the new filename

            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + ": " + sheetName);
            string newFilename = targetPath + "\\" + sheetName; //set the filename with full path, but no extension
            Console.WriteLine(newFilename);

            toolStripStatus.Text = "Exporting: " + sheetName; //update the status bar
            Excel.Worksheet tempSheet = (xlApp.Worksheets[i]); //Current tab will be saved to this in a new workbook
            tempSheet.Copy();
            Excel.Workbook tempBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;

            try
            {
                switch (exportFormat) //if the file does NOT exist OR if does and the the user wants to overwrite it, do the export and increase the sheetCount by 1
                {
                    case "CSV":
                        if (!File.Exists(newFilename + ".csv") || MessageBox.Show(sheetName + ".csv already exists. Overwrite?", "Confirm Overwrite", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            tempBook.Worksheets[1].SaveAs(newFilename, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                            sheetCount++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "XLSX":
                        if (!File.Exists(newFilename + ".xlsx") || MessageBox.Show(sheetName + ".xlsx already exists. Overwrite?", "Confirm Overwrite", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            tempBook.Worksheets[1].SaveAs(newFilename, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                            //tempSheet.SaveAs(newFilename, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                            sheetCount++;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Unexpected export format");
                        MessageBox.Show("Unexpected export format");
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                toolStripStatus.Text = "Error!";

                string errorMessage = "Error Exporting " + sheetName + System.Environment.NewLine + "Original Message: " + ex.Message;
                MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Error Exporting", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
                toolStripStatus.Text = "Ready";

                break;
            }
        }

        //Closing Processes Start ===================================================
        toolStripStatus.Text = "Process Finished";
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
        xlFile.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();
        Console.WriteLine(sheetCount.ToString() + " files exported.");
        MessageBox.Show(sheetCount.ToString() + " files exported.","Process Complete", MessageBoxButtons.OK ,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        toolStripStatus.Text = "Ready";
        //Closing Processes Finish ====================================================================================================
```

I expect the target file to be split into multiple files, one tab per file.

Using the code above, I get the same file copies with just the tab selected. I've tried a number of variations on the above since then, but nothing seems to be working better.

Comment: You'll have to provide more information.  Show what you're doing now and exactly what isn't working (what results you're getting vs. your expected results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely revamped your code. I'd like to give several notes:

1. In your UI you must set one of the Radiobuttons checked so that you wouldn't have to write in your code like *Error detecting output format*, i.e. the output format must be always set.
2. I couldn't figure it out what does `sourceFile` parameter do.
3. When dealing with file paths, always deal with [System.IO.Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path) static class which has lots of useful methods for working with paths.
4. Follow [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle (you break it when you save workbook).

   ```
   private void SplitFile(string targetPath, string sourceFile)
   {

       bool isSave;
       Excel.XlFileFormat fileFormat = Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook;

       string exportFormat = "";
       if (cboExcel.Checked) //set the output format
           exportFormat = "XLSX";
       else if (cboCsv.Checked)
           exportFormat = "CSV";

       Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application(); //object for controlling Excel
       Excel.Workbook xlFile = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(txtFilePath.Text); //open the source file

       xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false; //override Excel save dialog message
       int TabCount = xlFile.Worksheets.Count; //total count of the tabs in the file

       int sheetCount = 0; //this will be used to output the number of exported sheets
       for (int i = 1; i <= TabCount; i++) //for each sheet in the workbook...
       {
           isSave = true; //Must reset to true
           string sheetName = xlFile.Sheets[i].Name;
           string newFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, sheetName); //set the filename with full path, but no extension

           toolStripStatus.Text = "Exporting: " + sheetName; //update the status bar
           Excel.Worksheet tempSheet = xlApp.Worksheets[i]; //Current tab will be saved to this in a new workbook
           tempSheet.Copy();
           Excel.Workbook tempBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;

           try
           {
               switch (exportFormat) //if the file does NOT exist OR if does and the the user wants to overwrite it, do the export and increase the sheetCount by 1
               {
                   case "CSV":
                       newFilename += ".csv";
                       fileFormat = Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV;
                       break;
                   case "XLSX":
                       newFilename += ".xlsx";
                       fileFormat = Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook;
                       break;
               }

               if (File.Exists(newFilename))
                   isSave = (MessageBox.Show(sheetName + ".xlsx already exists. Overwrite?", "Confirm Overwrite", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Yes);

               if (isSave)
               {
                   tempBook.SaveAs(newFilename, fileFormat);
                   tempBook.Close(false);
                   sheetCount++;
               }

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               toolStripStatus.Text = "Error!";
               string errorMessage = "Error Exporting " + sheetName + System.Environment.NewLine + "Original Message: " + ex.Message;
               MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Error Exporting", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
               toolStripStatus.Text = "Ready";
           }
       }

       xlFile.Close(false);
       GC.Collect();
       GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
       GC.Collect();
       GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();

       MessageBox.Show("Well done!");

   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I tried to implement your suggestions and ran into an General Error:
Invalid Index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800200B (DISP_E_BANDINDEX))

Edit: It did manage to save the first tab as it's own file, so that's progress at least!

Edit 2: The Exception occurs at tempSheet.Copy();

Comment: Pleases, update your answer to actual code you now have so that I could investigate it.

Comment: In `switch` you, for some reason, refer to `tempSheet`, but you need to replace it with `tempBook.Worksheets[1]`.

Comment: For the CSV side of it? Yes, I haven't updated that part yet. Technically it works already how I want but since the Excel portion isn't working properly I don't see a reason to update it until it does and I clean up my code a bit.

Comment: It sounded like you were referring to the CSV portion of the code. Perhaps that's not what you meant. I've updated the code on both sides as you suggested, but I get the same exception.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It seems what I was missing in the last version of my code was I wasn't closing the temporary workbook. If I implement that into my code, everything works as expected. As I said, I was planning on cleaning up my code after I got everything working (I tried so many things I just wanted the damn thing to work), but you saved me a bit of trouble on that too. Thanks a ton for your help!